# Downloading files from the web in Amazon Workspace enviroment

Tags: amazon-web-services, browser, download, amazon-workspaces

I'm trying to set up a desktop for a client with Amazon Workspace (Standard with Amazon Linux 2 and Standard with Windows 10 (Server 2016 based)) and found out I can't download anything from the browsers (Firefox and Explorer), tried shutting off security settings and firewall with no success, I saw the following guide https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-file-download-ie/ but I cant seem to implement it in Workspace environment.

Any ideas for allowing file downloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the environment and using Firefox solved it.